# Find part of an ID using getElementsByTagName('*') / Wildcard

Tags: javascript, wildcard, innerhtml, getelementsbytagname

I´m still trying to work with JavaScript and i got a problem:

I got a easy html site for practice and in this site there is a 
`<p id="main_paragraph_two">... und Viel Erfolg!</p>`
 and also: `<p id="sub_paragraph_two">... und Viel Erfolg!</p>`

The task is: to change the Text ...und Viel Erfolg into ...und vielen Dank!

My coworker told me to use getElementsByTagName and than using a Wildcard ('*').

Now my Questions is: how can i change both of the p-tags to the text shown above?
*pls note! only javascript! also not using querySelectorAll (i know it works that way^^).

here is the JS i made so far:

```
function textchange()
        {
            var change = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
            for (var i = 0; i < change.length; i++)
            {
                if (document.getgetElementsByName('paragraph_two'))
                {
                    change[i].innerHTML = '...und Vielen Dank!';
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use querySelectorAll?

Comment: If you know they're P elements, why not `getElementsByTagName('p')` to reduce the size of the collection you're iterating over?

Comment: Scold your co-worker! ^

Comment: *__* omg i love you! this is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `getElementsByTagName` is relatively slow. Why don't you just add the IDs of the paragraphs to an array, loop through the array and then update the content.

For example:

```
function textChange( elems, replace )
{
    for( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ )
    {
        document.getElementById( elems[i] ).innerHTML = replace;
    }
}
```

Now, you may call the function as follows, where `elems` is an array of the IDs, and `replace` is the string to be used for the replacement:

```
textChange( ['main_paragraph_two', 'sub_paragraph_two'], '...und Vielen Dank!' );
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/99Lwuo1b/)

Comment: thanks for your help, but using the wildcard ('p') is working, but i should not use it.     i have to find out how i can change the a text with an ID ending with _paragraph_two withour using jQuery or Queryselector, only with the wildcard *